# change UITableViewCell of a FBFriendPickerViewController

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview

How is it possible to adjust an UITableViewCell of the tableview of a FBFriendPickerViewController with the Facebook SDK v3.2 for iOS?

Comment: I have not yet played around with FBFriendPickerViewController, but I assume it has a "tableView" property right? If so: given an instance of FBFriendPickerViewController that you have called pickerVC, check if pickerVC.dataSource == pickerVC. If so: then you could probably subclass FBFriendPickerViewController to override methods like cellForRowAtIndexPath: (remembering to send the same message to super)..